# Pages take 2 loadings to complete

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

On this website, https://toptees.store/linux-funny-cloud-computing I try to scrape sold span text but this website takes 2 time load to coming complete website. That's why data is not scraped.

My Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://toptees.store/linux-funny-cloud-computing"

reqs = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, 'lxml')
sold = soup.find_all("span", class_='ng-binding')
print(sold)
```

I also tried with selenium with Beautifulsoup

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))  # ,options=options

filepath = 'urls.txt'
with open(filepath) as f:
    urls = [i.strip() for i in f.readlines()]

titles = []
for url in urls:
    driver.get(url)
    driver.maximize_window()
    time.sleep(3)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    sold = soup.find('span', class_="ng-binding")
    print(sold)
```

The output is coming like this `[]` . How can I scrape this link with Beautifulsoup?

Comment: My guess is that those values are rendered with javascript, something requests cannot handle. You will probably want to use selenium to do this.

Comment: Yes. I tried with selenium but I couldn't complete it. When I tried to open this link in Chrome, I got a blank page because Selenium stopped loading after one load, but this site requires two loads.

Comment: IDK why it's requiring two loads, it doesn't on my end.  However you could send a refresh to selenium.

Comment: What information are you after, from that page?

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus Titles and Sold

Comment: @Chris I also tried with refresh, I add the selenium code in this post. `driver.refresh()`

Answer (score -1):

This is one way to get that information you're after:

```
import time as t
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import undetected_chromedriver as uc


options = uc.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')
options.add_argument("--window-size=1280,720")
# options.add_argument('--headless')

browser = uc.Chrome(options=options)
url = 'https://toptees.store/linux-funny-cloud-computing'

browser.get(url)
t.sleep(1)
browser.get(url)
t.sleep(7)
soup = bs(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
sold = soup.select_one('days-available[any-sold="campaign.sold"]')
title = soup.select_one('h1.campaign-name-title')
print(title.text, '|', [x for x in sold.text.split(' ') if len(x.strip()) > 0][0])
```

Result printed in terminal:

```
Linux funny Cloud Computing | 43
```

For undetected_chromedriver, please see https://pypi.org/project/undetected-chromedriver/ [instructions on how to set it up, etc]

Comment: I install undetected_chromedriver succesfully but it's showing this problem https://codeshare.io/Ado1Q8 . How can I solve this problem?

Comment: @RasedulIslam try it with `driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True)`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I tried many times with it, but it's not working and showing the same problem. It's opening a welcome chrome window but it's not taking me to the url. Can you check it again please?

Comment: The solution works... did you try updating your packages, and restarting your system? @RasedulIslam